# Pandas modifying whilst iterating

Tags: python, pandas, loops, class, dataframe

My question is nuanced and is related to modifying objects within a Dataframe. Please read properly or just skip over this question. I will of course do my best to concisely describe it.

In the Pandas documentation for pandas.DataFrame.iterrows there is a warning that:

*You should never modify something you are iterating over. This is not guaranteed to work in all cases. Depending on the data types, the iterator returns a copy and not a view, and writing to it will have no effect.*

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html

However the documentation for pandas.DataFrame.itertuples does not have this warning.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html

As a note I generally always use pandas.DataFrame.itertuples due to the performance benefits.

**Problem:**

I have a class below called **myclass** and this has a method called *add_year* which modifies an attribute, with an argument passed from another column in the same row of the Dataframe

I create a dataframe and one of the columns holds instances of this object.

I want to iterate through the rows in this column, applying the class method *add_year* to each instance with the parameter passed from the Dataframe

The code example below does this successfully. However I am concerned by the warning on pandas.DataFrame.iterrows that this may cause problems, because even though I am using pandas.DataFrame.itertuples I am modifying the Dataframe whilst iterating through it.

**Does anyone know if this method will cause problems? And if so what should I use?**

```
import pandas as pd

class myclass:

    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name

    def add_year(self,year):
        self.year = year

objOne = myclass('Andy')
objTwo = myclass('Joe')

d = {'myClassCol': [objOne, objTwo], 'OtherData': ['2018', '2019']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

for row in df.itertuples():
    df.at[row.Index,'myClassCol'].add_year(df.at[row.Index,'OtherData'])
```

Comment: Perhaps the biggest issue here is that DataFrames really aren't meant to store arbitrary objects - it kind of defaults the entire point of them.

Comment: @JonClements Arbitrary objects being anything that isn't a datatype?

Comment: pandas uses numpy underneath which works well with certain dtypes... In the example you've given, you'd ideally have a DataFrame of `df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Andy', 'Joe'], 'OtherData': [2018, 2019]})` and then use `.str` accessors, eg: `df['name'] = df['name'].str.upper()`. So you'd have your instance attributes as columns of the dataframe, each object's data would effectively be a row, and then you either use builtin things, or `.apply` a custom function to rows/columns instead of explicitly iterating...

Comment: @JonClements Ok interesting. In reality the object 'myclass' has a quite a range of attributes & methods, and the rest of the dataframe holds normal datatypes needed for the computation of methods in each 'myclass'

Comment: Umm... okay... hard to see without a more concrete example, but I'd probably write your loop as: `for obj in df.myClassCol: obj.capitalise_name()` as you don't need tuples in that case... You're also not in that case mutating the DF at all (no copies, no assignments, no indexing back to it, just mutating the underlying object referred to...)

Comment: @JonClements Ok thanks. Based on your comments however I am now thinking it might just be better for me to have a list of lists. Where each sub-list has a named tuple which was the Dataframe row and the arbitrary object. 

Then I can easily pass arguments through etc

Comment: Sounds like a maintenance nightmare... things like dropping a row in your dataframe will orphan it to the list of lists etc... so keeping them in sync would be fun... plus lots of other potential quirks I don't want to think about in too much detail. Have fun though :)

Comment: @JonClements Haha I'll try :)